# Python imports autocompletion

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me, filetype-python

I'm trying to configure vim for python development. Right now I'm working on code autocompletion feature. I'm using YouCompleteMe plugin and it seems to be working great but only when I've already imported given module. For example, if I type

```
import datetime
```

and then

```
datetime.
```

I get list of available classes/modules/functions etc.
What I'm missing is the possibility to get module suggestions when writing import statements. Datetime module seem to be trivial in this case, so I use Django framework as an example. I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
from django.
```

lists all modules within django, I choose one of them, e.g.  views

```
from django.views.
```

lists all modules within django.views, I choose e.g. generic

```
from django.views.generic import
```

And then I'd like to have autocompletion of classes, functions, variables available from this module e.g.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
```

Do you have any suggestion how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is very late but I found this question long before I came across the answer so I'm leaving this here. By adding the following to your .vimrc file you can load in your python virtualenv and then set a few ycm settings.

```
" python with virtualenv support
py << EOF
import os
import sys
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
EOF

let g:ycm_server_python_interpreter='python3'
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
map <leader>g :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
```